# Why the return of the regex is false?

Tags: javascript, regex

The code is showed as follows:

```
alert(/symbol([.\n]+?)symbol/gi.test('symbolbbbbsymbol'));
```

or

```
alert(/#([.\n]+?)#/gi.test('#bbbb#'));
```

Comment: Change to `/<(.+?)>/gi` . Also, don't parse HTML with RegExp that's a horrible idea http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Why did you change the code in the question?

Comment: I am sorry for the incomplete code posted before.What I want is to find all strings between two symbols such as '#***#' or '<symbol>***</symbol>'

Comment: The principle is the same: `[.]` matches literally the `.` character and nothing else.

Answer (score 8):

Because you are looking for dots with a character class inside of `<` and `>`.  Remove the character class:

```
/<(.+?)>/
```

### Clarification after question edit:

First code block should be using this pattern: `/symbol(.+?)symbol/`

Second code block should be using this pattern: `/#(.+?)#/`

Answer (score 2):

The regex returns false because a dot loses its special power to match any character (but newlines) when placed within a character class `[]` - it only matches a simple `"."`.

To match and capture the substring delimited at either end by the same *single character*, the most efficient pattern to use is

```
/#([^#]+)#/
```

To match and capture the substring delimited at either end by the same sequence of *characters*, the pattern to use is

```
/symbol(.+?)symbol/
```

or, if you want to match across newlines

```
/symbol([\s\S]+?)symbol/
```

where `[\s\S]` matches any space or non-space character, which equates to *any* character.

The `?` is inlcuded to make the pattern match *lazily*, i.e. to make sure the match ends on the first occurence of `"symbol"`.